# Perforce edit/open only working via depot name, not local name

Tags: perforce

I have my perforce client set up and had a problem trying to simply do a "p4 edit file.txt" from a subdirectory of the client root where file.txt is a checked-in file local to that directory. In other words, if I did "p4 have" I would see "//depot/folder/file.txt#2 - /proj/folder/file.txt" in the list. p4 sync seems fine. However, "p4 edit file.txt" would give the error "File(s) not on client."

I did finally get a p4 edit to work by using the depot name. "p4 edit //depot/folder/file.txt" DID work and strangely enough it modified the local file to have write permissions.

Any idea what the problem is? I have other clients on the same system for different projects that work the way you would expect, by referencing the local file name.

Comment: Do you have your P4CLIENT environment variable (or the P4CLIENT setting in your .p4config file) set to the correct client name ?  Try running "p4 -c CLIENT_NAME edit file.txt" - if that works then Perforce is not picking up your P4CLIENT value.

Comment: If I do a "p4 set" I can see the expect values of P4CLIENT, P4CONFIG, P4PORT and P4USER. I tried what you suggested and it did not work, still "file(s) not on client."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've encountered problems like this using overlay mappings (entries in the client view with leading plus signs.

I've also encountered problems like this by changing the client view, but not performing a full 'p4 sync' afterwards to re-arrange all the files on my workstation to match the updated view.

Did you, by any chance, fit into either of those scenarios?

Have you tried running 'p4 where file.txt' and 'p4 where //depot/folder/file.txt'? Often that command is very useful for figuring out why the filename syntax on your command line isn't successfully resolving to a repository file name.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how I should use the output of "p4 where" to troubleshoot? When I do those two commands you suggested, I see the same output for both, basically: //depot/folder/file.txt //<client name>/folder/file.txt /actual/path/on/disk/folder/file.txt

Comment: This did lead me to resolving the issue. In my client view path I was missing a slash before the "..." After fixing this and re-syncing it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and I wanted to document it here as it was a bugger to track down, and a google search may lead someone with the same fault here.

I had a branch, lets call it //depot/foo and I made a another branch of it for producing a variant, call it //depot/foo_bar. The steps to branch foo_bar from foo where:

```
  p4 branch foo_bar
```

To create a branch spec, then

```
  p4 integrate -b foo_bar
  p4 submit
```

I also added foo_bar to my client workspace.

After this, I could edit, access, whatever, everything on the foo_bar branch in P4V but any command line command I tried with p4 got the error 'file(s) not on client'.

To be clear - worked in P4V - 'file(s) not on client' in p4 command line.

Turns out, there was an error in the branch specification, I had added an extra '.' e.g.

```
  View:
    //depot/foo/... //depot/foo_bar/....
```

I tried removing the spurious full stop and reintegrating. This resulted in the command line working fine but P4V having two copies of every file in the branch, one normal file and one file name with a '.' at the end. Again, to be clear, the first time around the files looked normal - no spurious '.' on the file names, after the reintegration - double the number of files but only in the p4v depot view - there was only one copy of each file in the workspace on disk.

In the end, I deleted the branch and started again from scratch.

System configuration

- OS: Windows 7 64-bit
- P4 Server version: P4D/LINUX26X86_64/2012.1/512349 (2012/08/18)
- P4V version: Rev. Perforce Visual Client/NTX64/2012.1/500245
- P4 Client version: Rev.  P4/NTX64/2012.1/490371 (2012/07/02).